# Find a positive integer $i$ such that $9i + 1$ divides $2 \times 10^i - 1$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

I have written a Python program running over $i$, but up to billions there is no solution, so I guess there is no solution. Trying to prove that, I looked at multiplicative order, but I do not get a grip on $9i +1$. Anybody an idea for the proof (or finding a huge $i$)?

Comment: Thanks. This I had already figured out, $9i +1$ must obviously be odd, and $i$ cannot be $5k+1$ because $9i+1$ cannot be a multiple of 5, but that is as far as I got.